# Should form model be used in all forms in a yii application?

Tags: php, yii, webforms

What wrong is it in creating a simple form tag in html to hold a small form whose validation can be written easily instead of creating a form model to hold the rules and labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this before abandoning the form model.  The form model does a lot of things for you.  Some of these things will take a lot of effort to build for yourself.  Here is a quick list:

- It maintains code consistency within your app
- It maintains UI consistency for the user
- It provides validation
- It provides Error Handling
- It helps prevent certain attacks like SQL Injection
- It can help prevent other attacks if you turn on CSRF tagging
- Client side validation is built in and can be enabled with a configuration
- Ajax functionality is built in and can be enabled with a configuration

There are a lot of things you are giving up.  Even for a simple form.  And those things go beyond validation and HTML formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a simplest way, it will not be wrong.

FormModels should help you to organize a lot of validation rules, scenarios and other. If creation of FormModel will take more effort than just write validation in controller, this isn't case for FormModel.

Comment: Forgot to say, Yii validators can be used outside FormModels, like `if ((new CEmailValidator)->validateValue($form['email']))`